# How do I emphasize the 'BE' form of words without formatting?

Tags: word-choice, emphasis

I was reading a paragraph in Last Generation magazine. Here it is:

> I was attending a closed meeting for recovering drug addicts, but I
>   wasn't a drug addict. I felt the need to lie in order to be there with
>   a friend who *was* a drug addict.

As you can see, *was* was emphasized using italic formatting. What's the best and succinct or to say, generally accepted way to emphasize the same in words?

That is, how can I add emphasis to "was" in the above paragraph if I don't have any formatting options to add emphasis and I've to manage with just words but still emphasize it?

Comment: In words (ignoring the possibility of simply placing extra vocal stress on ***was***) you can make the meaning clear with *a friend who **actually** was a drug addict* (italics mine, obviously, but it still works without, in the written form). Alternatives include ***really, in fact, genuinely,*** etc. It would also be screamingly obvious what you meant if you'd started off by saying *but I wasn't a drug addict **myself*** (again, the relevant emphasis will be conveyed without switching typeface).

Comment: You could also set "was" apart using dashes... "...a friend who - was - a drug addict." Or do dashes count as "formatting"? Is this to be written or spoken?

Comment: Another term for the same use: ***indeed*** ("who was *indeed* a ...")

Comment: @Catija probably for spoken. Was just curious of what it would be. I knew of really, in fact, but thought there was something other than this. Thanks commentators.

Comment: What is the (sic) for?

Comment: @Amit [That's not what "sic" does.](http://data.grammarbook.com/blog/definitions/sic/)

Answer (score 3):

> I was reading a paragraph in Last Generation magazine. Here it is:
>
> > > I was attending a closed meeting for recovering drug addicts, but I wasn't a drug addict. I felt the need to lie in order to be there with
> > >        a friend who *was* a drug addict.
>
> As you can see, *was* was emphasized using italic formatting. What's the best and succinct or to say, generally accepted way to emphasize the same in words?
>
> That is, how can I add emphasis to "was" in the above paragraph if I don't have any formatting options to add emphasis and I've to manage with just words but still emphasize it?

We can use words which  contrast the expectations of the reader with the facts. We can do this because readers expect two similar sentences together to be the same. So any words which show that the facts are *different* from what people would suspect will give *contrastive emphasis*. They will show that the second thing is different from the first.

Some good phrases to use are *actually*, *indeed*, *really* and *in fact*. If we use these, we won't need any special formatting for the Original Poster's sentence:

- I was attending a closed meeting for recovering drug addicts, but I wasn't a drug addict. I felt the need to lie in order to be there with a friend who actually was a drug addict.
- I was attending a closed meeting for recovering drug addicts, but I wasn't a drug addict. I felt the need to lie in order to be there with a friend who indeed was a drug addict.
- I was attending a closed meeting for recovering drug addicts, but I wasn't a drug addict. I felt the need to lie in order to be there with a friend who really was a drug addict.
- I was attending a closed meeting for recovering drug addicts, but I wasn't a drug addict. I felt the need to lie in order to be there with a friend who in fact was a drug addict.

There are many more phrases we could use. We could also change some of the positions of these phrases. The main point is that these are some useful phrases to give positive emphasis to sentences - which are useful to give contrast with negative clauses or ideas.

However, almost any adjunct (adverbial) that we use after the word *was* will emphasise that the clause is positive (unlike the previous clause, which is negative). So even if we use the word *unfortunately* with commas this will still emphasise the difference:

Several of these phrases are listed in comments above!

Answer (score 1):

Usually the alternative to using italics for emphasis is using CAPITALS, particularly with fonts which don't have an italic variant or are already in italics.

Answer (score 1):

> I was attending a closed meeting for recovering drug addicts, but I wasn't a drug addict. I felt the need to lie in order to be there with a friend who was a drug addict.

One simple way to emphasize the *was* is to end the sentence with it:

> I was attending a closed meeting for recovering drug addicts, but I wasn't a drug addict. I felt the need to lie in order to be there with a friend who was.

I might simplify a little further:

> I was attending a closed meeting for recovering drug addicts, but I wasn't one. I felt the need to lie in order to be there with a friend who was.